# image doesn't appear with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show a 'processing' image on my code using javascript. So what I intend to do is to display the processing image at the start of the process, perform the operation and hide the image. This is just to let user know that the system is currently doing some stuff.

My code looks as below. filters method perform some jquery operation on the page such as filtering existing data and reformatting the layout (no network operation involved)

```
$('#divProcessing').show();
filters(_selectedStatusFilter, null);
$('#divProcessing').hide();
```

But the processing image doesn't appear. I tried debugging this with Firebug in Firefox and if I stick a break point at `$('#divProcessing').hide();` I see that the image does appear, but it doesn't seem to appear if I don't have any breakpoints. filters method itself is not very quick and does plenty of stuff with the page elements, so this perhaps remove the chance that the process is so fast that the image doesn't appear?

Thanks for reading and hope you'll be able to find me a solution.

Please ask any question if I am not clear enough.

Comment: Can you share your HTML code, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document does not get updated with any changes as long as synchronous JS code is running.

You have to "de-couple" your longer running code from the current execution context, so that the rendering engine gets handed control again and can update the display - one way of doing that is to execute the later code using setTimeout:

```
$('#divProcessing').show();
setTimeout(function() {
  filters(_selectedStatusFilter, null);
  $('#divProcessing').hide();
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

if your `filters(_selectedStatusFilter, null);` do something asynchronously (like $.ajax) calling you need to call `.hide()` in callback function of async method or in custom event event handler, whick you can rise with `.trigger()` on `filters()` method exitinig.

Comment: OP said: <<no network operation involved>> so i don't think there is any async operation. CBroe's answer seems more appropriate here